# how to download your application from bluemix?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

How to download the node.js starter application after making some changes on the code on bluemix? Image 1 - Document shows click on "view quick starter"

[image]

Image 2 - But i dont see any "view Quick Starter " tab on my overview page

Comment: Image one did not upload properly ... but its the same as in the docs section under the  "Downloading your Node.js starter application" header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download the starter code there is the START CODING tab in the application dashboard. If you want to download the code after you have made changes than you must have added GIT for the project and you can access the code from the GIT repository.